# How to replace each word of a string from a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I wanted to replace each word from myString with that from myList. My code only replaces the last word from myString. Any idea how it can be done.

```
from itertools import product

myList = ["abandon","ability","absurd","abuse"]
myString = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8"


comb = product(myList, repeat=1)
for i in comb:
    missing = ' '.join(i)
    myString = myString.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
    #print (myString)

    myString = str(myString) + str(" ") + str(missing)
    print (myString)
```

My Output:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 abandon
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 ability
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 absurd
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 abuse
```

Output Needed:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 abandon
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 ability
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 absurd
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 abuse

word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 abandon word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 ability word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 absurd word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 abuse word8

word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 abandon word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 ability word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 absurd word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 abuse word7 word8

word1 word2 word3 word4 abandon word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 ability word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 absurd word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 word4 abuse word6 word7 word8

word1 word2 word3 abandon word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 ability word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 absurd word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 word3 abuse word5 word6 word7 word8

word1 word2 abandon word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 ability word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 absurd word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 word2 abuse word4 word5 word6 word7 word8

word1 abandon word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 ability word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 absurd word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
word1 abuse word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8

abandon word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
ability word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
absurd word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
abuse word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8
```

Comment: The question isn't clear on exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just wanted to replace each of of my string from a list. I am not sure if it can be called a permutation.

Comment: So your output is only shows a subset of what's required. Perhaps you can help illustrate that if you add "..." to indicate the pattern of the series. The way how it is written, it's not obvious why only 3 words are being selected from the list and it's not obvious why only certain words are being replaced. Also it is not obvious why the words are being replaced in reverse order. Also, whilst you refer to "My code", you haven't shown it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based solely on the output you desire, I would do something like that:

```
myList = ["abandon", "ability", "absurd", "abuse"]
myString = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8"

splitted = myString.split()
output = ""
for j in range(len(splitted)-1, -1, -1):
    for i in myList:
        total = " ".join(splitted[0:j]) + " " + i + " " + " ".join(splitted[j+1:len(splitted)]) + "\n"
            output += total.lstrip()
        output+= "\n"
    
print(output)
```

Iterate backward through your `myString` (transformed as a list with splitted) and find the correct index at which you want to place your word

Answer (score 0):

A variation is to create a word list from your myString and to change the words in the word list before printing, and change the word back after we're done:

```py
myList = ["abandon", "ability", "absurd", "abuse"]
myString = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8"
words = myString.split()
for j in reversed(range(len(words))):
    old_word = words[j]
    for new_word in myList:
        words[j] = new_word
        print(" ".join(words))
    words[j] = old_word
```